# Solr Aliases: Can i search using an alias and will the results be sorted if the alias is pointed to multiple indices

Tags: solr, solr-search

did anyone has experience using aliases in Solr pointing to multiple indices and using the alias to perform search query agains the indices that are pointed to the alias. If yes i am curious how the results will appear ,will they be presented in batches for each underlying index or wil be presented as a single set of results sorted

Comment: I don't understand: indices = indexes? And how do you define an alias to point to more than one collection?

Comment: you are right i missed that point ,abstract from solr documentaiton  Starting with version 8.1 SolrCloud supports using alias names in collection commands where normally a collection name is expected. This works only when the following criteria are satisfied:

an alias must not refer to more than one collection